# How to use the map function on a vector of maps in clojure

Tags: vector, clojure, functional-programming

I have a function which generates a vector of coordinates in a square board. The result of running this function is something of the form

```
 [{:x 1, :y 0} {:x 0, :y 1} {:x 2, y:3} {:x 3, :y 4}]
```

After running this function, I need to apply another function to the result above. Since I'd be mapping a function over a collection, I thought using the map function would be appropriate. As such, I wrote the following method:

```
(defn attack [x y] (map (fn [coord] (println (get coord :x))) [{:x 1, :y 0} {:x 0, :y 1}]))
```

(I've also tried the example above with get-in instead of get, to no avail)

This is not the final form of the method, and instead is just something I tried to see if I could at least see something printed to the terminal after running

```
clojure myscript.clj
```

However, nothing comes out of it and it doesn't seem to matter whether I return a value from the fn function or not. For example, this

```
(defn attack [x y] (map (fn [coord] coord) [{:x 1, :y 0} {:x 0, :y 1}]))
```

also returns nothing. Does anyone know how I could at least get access to the values inside the vector in my fn function?

Lastly, does it matter whether my vector is generated by a call to another function?
For example,

```
(defn attack [x y] (map (fn [coord] coord) (get-attack-coordinates x y)))
```

would this be a problem? I'm guessing not, but I thought it was a good idea to ask just in case. 
Thank you all for reading :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map` does return in this case

```
(map (fn [coord] coord) [{:x 1, :y 0} {:x 0, :y 1}])
;; => ({:x 1, :y 0} {:x 0, :y 1})
```

Note that in this case:

```
(map (fn [coord] (println (get coord :x))) [{:x 1, :y 0} {:x 0, :y 1}])
```

It will first print 1 and then 0 and then return

```
(nil nil)
```

because `println` returns `nil`.

Furthermore, if you want access to the `x` and `y` you can also use [destructuring](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring):

```
(map (fn [{:keys [x y]}] [x y]) [{:x 1, :y 0} {:x 0, :y 1}])
```

Note that I tried these things in the REPL:

[image: The REPL]

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. [**If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303816/625403).

Comment: Hi Erwin! Your code worked for me, thank you! I think I was misplacing a parenthesis so that the map function ended sooner than I expected. I'm not sure on why it didn't throw an error, but it worked anyway.

Answer (score 3):

`(map f xs)` *always* returns something. It's impossible not to. If you think it doesn't, there's something wrong with how you're measuring, not with your `map` call.  Include more code about the structure of your program, not just this one snippet.